# Error while importing shapefile into Oracle db using geotools

Tags: shapefile, geotools, oracle-spatial

I am trying to import shape file into Oracle database but I am running TNS listener error:

> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
> The Connection descriptor used by the client was:

I have the service name of the database not the SID which I am passing in the
`params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "test")`

Does this can only take SID/Service Name because its internally making the URL like

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@test:1521:test`. I guess it should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@test:1521/test` instead of :

I was able to make a connection via SQL Developer. I'm not sure what could be incorrect here.

Below is the Code for the same

```java
package com.polk.geotools.gis.QuickStart;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.DefaultTransaction;
import org.geotools.data.FeatureStore;
import org.geotools.data.Transaction;
import org.geotools.data.oracle.OracleNGDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStoreFactory;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.AttributeDescriptor;
import org.opengis.filter.Filter;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;

public class ShapeToSdo {
    public  ShapeToSdo (String shploc) throws FactoryException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

        String path = shploc;
                ShapefileDataStore shp = new ShapefileDataStore(new File(path).toURL());
                //THIS IS CRUCIAL FOR GREEK CHARS parsing
                //shp.setCharset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-7"));
                //IF NOT GREEK JUST OMMIT IT OR SET IT TO UTF_8
                shp.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.USER.key, "test");
                params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.PASSWD.key, "test");
                params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.HOST.key, "test");
                params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.PORT.key, "1521");
                params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "test");
                params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, "oracle");
                DataStore oracle = new OracleNGDataStoreFactory().createDataStore(params);
                if(oracle != null && oracle.getTypeNames() != null)
                    System.out.println("Oracle connected");
                System.out.println("oracle.getTypeNames()"+oracle.getTypeNames());
                String typeName = shp.getTypeNames()[0].toUpperCase();

                System.out.println("shp.getTypeNames()[0]===="+shp.getTypeNames()[0]);
                if(!Arrays.asList(oracle.getTypeNames()).contains(typeName)){
                    System.out.println("shp.getSchema()"+shp.getSchema());
                    oracle.createSchema(shp.getSchema());
                }
                FeatureStore oraStore = (FeatureStore) oracle.getFeatureSource(typeName);
                oraStore.removeFeatures(Filter.INCLUDE);
                
                SimpleFeatureType targetSchema = (SimpleFeatureType) oraStore.getSchema();
                SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(targetSchema);
                
                
                FeatureIterator fi = shp.getFeatureSource().getFeatures().features();
                SimpleFeatureType sourceSchema = shp.getSchema();
                
                Transaction t = new DefaultTransaction();
                oraStore.setTransaction(t);
                while(fi.hasNext()) {
                    SimpleFeature source = (SimpleFeature) fi.next();
                
                    for(AttributeDescriptor ad : sourceSchema.getAttributeDescriptors()) {
                        String attribute = ad.getLocalName();
                        String passAtrr = attribute.toUpperCase();
                        
                        builder.set(passAtrr, source.getAttribute(attribute));
                        }
                    
                    oraStore.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(builder.buildFeature(null)));
                }
                t.commit();
                t.close();
                
            }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ShapeToSdo so = new ShapeToSdo("D:\\Git\\GIS spatial changes\\Shoreline Files\\county_spatial_erase_poc.shp");
        } catch (FactoryException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem , when I used /test instead of test in
params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "test") , it passed

Further I faced ojdbc14 issue where I get No Authetication Protocol error , but when I used ojdbc8 because I was using Java version 8, it worked for me.